# How do I retrieve the email address associated with a session token from the Google Data / Google Contacts API?

Tags: java, gdata, google-data-api, authsub, gdata-java-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one retrieve the email address of a user with GData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484188/how-does-one-retrieve-the-email-address-of-a-user-with-gdata)

Using the GData Java client (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/), I create an authsub request URL by using `AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl()`. I then exchange this for a session token using `AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken()` which all works fine. (Using "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" as the scope for Contacts)

I can see in the examples and Javadocs how to go about getting the contacts for this session token, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the email address that's just been authenticated.

<sub>Some of the wording in the documentation makes it seem like this is intentional (to be unable to retrieve that user's login information) but that seems like a gaping hole in functionality to me?</sub>

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484188/how-does-one-retrieve-the-email-address-of-a-user-with-gdata ?

Answer (score 0):

Google intentionally hides login information in all of its APIs, which includes the user's email address.